# Printing from swift uiwebview

Tags: ios, swift, printing, uiwebview

I can print my UIWebview content, but it prints on two pages, how can I scale it down to fit one page ?

My code:

```
@IBAction func printWebPage(sender: UIBarButtonItem) 
{
  let url = MainWebView.request?.URL
  let stringurl = url?.absoluteString

  let pic = UIPrintInteractionController.sharedPrintController()
  let printInfo : UIPrintInfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary: nil)

  printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputType.General
  printInfo.jobName = url  

  pic!.printInfo = printInfo
  pic!.printFormatter = MainWebView.viewPrintFormatter()
  pic!.showsPageRange = false

  pic!.presentAnimated(true, completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Comment: Do anyone have an answer to my question ?

Answer (score 3):

**From your comment:**

```
var webView = UIWebView()
let pic = UIPrintInteractionController.sharedPrintController()
let printInfo : UIPrintInfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary: nil)

// General: Text, Graphics and images.
// Photo: Black and white or color images.
// PhotoGrayscale: Black and white and grayscale images
// Grayscale: Gray scale general. (Black and white)
printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputType.General

pic!.printInfo = printInfo

pic!.printFormatter = webView.viewPrintFormatter()
pic!.showsPageRange = true
```

The only thing missing is the closure, and you will have to develop that on your own (I am sorry!)

Comment: I mean I want to print the content of the uiwebview to a printer

Comment: you can achieve that with the UIPrinter: [link to developer page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPrinter_class/index.html)

Comment: UIPrinter only tells about the printer not how to print. I am looking for something similar to this http://www.xappsoftware.com/wordpress/2011/05/26/printing-uiwebview-content/ but in swift code

Comment: I don't understand what should the closure do ?

Comment: For the closure I used the following script: `pic.present(animated: true, completionHandler:{ (controller, success, error) -> Void in ... })`